# Live-recorded base64-encoded audio from MediaRecorder is broken

Tags: javascript, php, base64, web-mediarecorder

I wrote a simple page on js and php to live record audio from microphone. Logic is simple:

JS

1. Get chunk of data from mic;
2. Base64 encode it and urlencode it;
3. Send it via POST request;

PHP

4. Base64 decode data;
5. (re)Write to .ogg file;
6. Repeat 1 after delay.

The data is successfully written to file, but when I try to play it, player says that file is broken.

The blob solution from [Mozilla guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start) is worked for me, I want exactly PHP solution with saving (rewriting) to file.

The full code below, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
file_put_contents("r.ogg", base64_decode($_POST["data"]));
exit;   
}
?>

<script>
var mediaRecorder = null;
let chunks = [];

if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
   console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (
      {
         audio: true
      })
      .then(function(stream) {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.start(2000);
        
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
            const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
            chunks = [];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
            reader.onloadend = function() {
            var data = reader.result.split(";base64,")[1]; 
            requestp2("a.php", "data="+encodeURIComponent(data));
            }
}
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
         console.log('The following getUserMedia error occurred: ' + err);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}

function requestp2(path, data)
{
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', path, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.send(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: typescript friendly version of splitting the reader result:   var data = (<string>reader.result).split(";base64,")[1];

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to choose your audio format and codec by specifying a media type in your Blob constructor. You Can't Do That™.

Specify the media type in your [MediaRecorder constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) instead.  Something like this, not debugged!

```js
        ...
        /* here's the media type definition vvv */
        mrOptions = {mimeType: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'}
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, mrOptions)
        mediaRecorder.start(2000)
        
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            ...
            const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type : mediaRecorder.mimeType })
            ...
```

There may also be some trouble with your handling of the consecutive `e.data` chunks MediaRecorder passes to your `ondataavailable` handler. To make a valid playable file you must concatenate all those chunks into the file. If you can't get it to work ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for feed back. It seems that only first chuck is playable. I think, it need to be stoped and then started again every time I want to send data

Comment: No, that's not right. If you concatenate the chunks, they are definitely playable. (I have a widely deployed app that relies on that behavior.) But it's really important to concatenate them in the right order.

Comment: @O.Jones can you please guide me on how to concatenate? I'm stuck at the same level.

Comment: if you @O.Jones try to play each blob chunk separately, only first chunk is playable, the subsequent chunks are not playable because they will not have file signature in them. I've only encountered the problem while implementing realtime speech-to-text but don't know the solution. Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I don't get your question @FirojSiddiki. But if you ignore any calls to your `.ondataavailable(event)` handler or discard any call's `event.data` item, you will not be able to play the stream. It's possible, but extremely intricate, to program around this as long as you have the first two, or maybe three, `event.data` chunnks. See [npm ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebml).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that seems only first chunk had like signature a label or something else, and hence could be played. So I had to add an interval to stop and play `mediaRecorder` every time.

Also the format of the file was not `ogg` but `webm`.

The full working code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
file_put_contents("r.webm", base64_decode($_POST["data"]));
exit;   
}
?>

<script>
var mediaRecorder = null;
var delay = 2000;

if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
   console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (
      {
         audio: true
      })
      .then(function(stream) {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'audio/webm; codecs=opus'});
        mediaRecorder.start(); 
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            var blob = e.data;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
            reader.onloadend = function() {
            var data = reader.result.split(";base64,")[1]; 
            requestp2("a.php", "data="+encodeURIComponent(data));
            }
}
setInterval(function(){
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.start();
                }, delay);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
         console.log('The following getUserMedia error occurred: ' + err);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}
function requestp2(path, data)
{
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', path, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.send(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: is this the way you went forward or tried to concatenate as advised by O Jones?